# store the filtered requests from scrapy dupefilter

Tags: scrapy

I am getting this from the stats after `scrapy crawl test`

`'dupefilter/filtered': 288,` how can I store the filtered requests into a .txt file (or any type) so I view later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to make 2 things:

1. Set [`DUPEFILTER_DEBUG`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-debug) setting to `True` - it will add all
   filtered requests into log
2. Set [`LOG_FILE`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-file) to save log in
       txt file.

One of possible way to do it - by setting `custom_settings` spider attribute:

`....`

```
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
....
    custom_settings = {
        "DUPEFILTER_DEBUG":True,
        "LOG_FILE": "log.txt"}
....
    def parse(self, response):
    ....
```

You will have log lines like this:
`2019-12-21 20:34:07 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/4/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/)`

**UPDATE** 
To save only dupefilter logs:

`....`

```
from logging import FileHandler

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
....
    custom_settings = {
        "DUPEFILTER_DEBUG":True,
        # "LOG_FILE": "log.txt"} # - optional
....
    def start_requests(self):
        # Adding file handler to dupefilter logger:
        dupefilter_log_filename = "df_log.txt" 
        self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df.logger.addHandler(FileHandler(dupefilter_log_filename, delay=False, encoding="utf-8"))

    def parse(self, response):
    ....
```

Additional info:

- Scrapy logging [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)
- Python `logging` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

Comment: It works,but the `log.txt` is saving all scrapy logs